# .NET tool for browsing MDB database

Tags: .net, database, ms-access, jet

I'm looking for a solution to provide MDB database viewing capabilities in my WinForms application. The goal is to allow user browsing tables, columns and rows. Any open-source or freeware widget available for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you don't need a special widget for this.
You can do it quite easily yourself, only with built-in .net stuff and a bit of Access knowledge.

1) Browsing tables (=getting a list of all existing tables):
Every MDB (at least A2000 and A2003, I have never used A2007 and above) has a hidden table named `MSysObjects`.
It contains ALL objects (forms and reports as well, for example) but you can filter on the `Type` column to get only the tables:
Type = 1 : local tables
Type = 6 : linked tables

2) Showing the content of one table:
Just load it into a DataSet and display it in a grid.

Comment: MSysObjects exists in the later versions of office too