# How to rename primary key value in Access DB

Tags: ms-access, key, rename

I have a MS Access DB with a primary key on the parent table and 82 other tables.
New data will be coming with new name for the primary key

```
Before      New
RS182       X182RS
RS188       X188RS
RD301       X301RD
```

Is there a way to rename the primary key value in bulk on all the tables in the DB because I want to associate all previous historical data to the new name value.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that hard to code, at least if I understand the following correct from your question:

- the primary key column exists in every table
- it has the same name in every table (I'll use `ID` in my example)
- the existing values are all in the same format ("RS182" --> two letters and three numbers)

To get a list of all tables in your database, you can take a look at the [hidden table `MSysObjects`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5955967/6884).

And then you just have to loop through the tables and update the `ID` column.
A quick example (works on my machine):

```
Public Function Test()

    Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "select name from msysobjects where type = 1 and name not like 'msys*'"

    Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
    Do While Not RS.EOF

        SQL = "update " & RS("name") & " set ID = 'X' & Mid([ID],3) & Left([ID],2);"

        CurrentDb.Execute SQL, dbFailOnError

        RS.MoveNext
    Loop
    RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: @HansUp: Never thought about it before...just googled it and found [this](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/bestpractices.htm). Is this the only reason or is there more?

Comment: I strongly agree with what Tony says about it on that page.  I would add that turning SetWarnings off is bad simply because it suppresses information.  Consider this Stack Overflow question where SetWarnings off was a huge obstacle to efficient trouble-shooting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115247/does-ms-access-suppress-primary-key-violations-on-inserts

Comment: Okay, you convinced me :-) Honestly, I hardly ever execute SQL locally in Access (I mainly use Access as a front-end for SQL Server) and I never thought about the implications of `SetWarnings False`. Answer edited!

Answer (score 1):

Based on that sample, it seems there is a consistent pattern between the new and old primary key values.

```
? "X" & Right("RS182", 3) & Left("RS182", 2)
X182RS
```

If that is true, then use a series of UPDATE statements to replace the old values with the new.  But first make a backup copy of your database for safekeeping.

For example, if the primary key field for YourTable is named ID:

```
UPDATE YourTable
Set ID = "X" & Right(ID, 3) & Left(ID, 2);
```

If YourTable is included in any defined relationships, you will first need to drop those relationships (or at least uncheck the "enforce referential integrity" option for them), then restore the relationships after updating the primary key values.

Also removing the primary key property from ID should allow the UPDATE to complete faster.  Re-assign the primary key afterward.

Since you have 82 tables which require this conversion, you could create a VBA procedure to do it.

```
Public Sub ConvertPKeyValues(ByVal pTable As String, _
        ByVal pField As String)
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strSql As String
    strSql = "UPDATE [" & pTable & "]" & vbCrLf & _
        "Set [" & pField & "] = 'X' & " & _
        "Right([" & pField & "], 3) & " & _
        "Left([" & pField & "], 2);"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    db.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Call the procedure with each table name and the name of the relevant field in that table.  You should also add an error handler for any problems which dbFailOnError exposes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify a PK if you have related records in the other tables.
So the trick here is to temporarily modify all those relationships (I suppose they exist and that Referential Integrity is enabled - otherwise I wouldn't even talk to you :), and enable the Cascade Update option.
Don't forget to turn that option off once your data goes back in prod !!